# How do I log stderr and stdout synchronously, but print stderr to screen only?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr

This is a task that I try to do pretty often. 
I want to log both stderr and stdout to a log file. But I only want to print to console stderr.

I've tried with tee, but once I've merge stderr and stdout using "2>&1". I can not print stdout to the screen anymore since both my pipes are merged.

Here is a simple example of what I tried

./dosomething.sh | tee -a log 2>&1.
Now I have both stderr and stdout to the log and the screen.

Any Ideas?

Based on some reading on this web site, this question has been asked. 
[Write STDOUT & STDERR to a logfile, also write STDERR to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871233/write-stdout-stderr-to-a-logfile-also-write-stderr-to-screen)

And also a question very similar here:
[Save stdout, stderr and stdout+stderr synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497817/save-stdout-stderr-and-stdoutstderr-synchronously)

But neither of them are able to redirect both stdout+stderr to a log and stderr to the screen while stdoud and stderr are synchronously written to the log file.

Comment: @Tomalak The OP tried `tee` with `2>&1`. Was there something he's missing?

Comment: @chrisaycock: The commands he used. Precisely.

Comment: I've edited the question to be a bit more precise. Giving an example and refering the the existing questions on stack overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get this working in bash:

```
(./tmp.sh 2> >(tee >(cat >&2) >&1)) > tmp.log
```

This does not work correctly in zsh (the prompt does not wait for the process to exit), and does not work at all in dash. A more portable solution may be to write a simple C program to do it.

Comment: I think `dash` and other simple, POSIX-like shells can't express this at all. +1, seems to work.

Comment: When I use this I need to press enter to get back to prompt. Typing a command and then enter runs that command. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working with this script in bash.

```
mkfifo stdout 
mkfifo stderr 

rm -f out 
cat stderr | tee -a out & 
cat stdout >> out & 
(echo "stdout";  
 grep;  
 echo "an other stdout";  
 echo "again stdout";  
 stat) 2> stderr > stdout 

rm -f stdout 
rm -f stderr
```

The order of the output is preserved. With this script the process ends correctly.

Note: I used grep and stat without parameter to generate stdout.

Comment: The accepted solution (from Random832) does get executed in the background. See here the command does not print in the rigth order.


$ echo line; ((echo line2; grep) 2> >(tee >(cat >&2) >&1)) > tmp.log; echo line3
line
line3

$ Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.