# stdout and stderr are out-of-order when a bash script is run from Atom

Tags: bash, atom-editor

I tried to write a little program to list a non existing directory and echo done, in a `.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls notexist
echo 'done'
```

But my console outputs done on the first line, before the error message to list the nonexisting directory:

```
done
ls: notexist: No such file or directory
```

I don't think bash creates a thread automatically for each line of code, does it? I'm using terminal in macOS Big Sur.

Edit: I'm accessing terminal indirectly from the `script` package of the Atom text editor in macOS Big Sur. The error goes away if I run code directly in console via `./file.sh`.

Comment: Bash won't do this _on its own_, but it can happen if your stdout and stderr aren't copies of the same fd (because when they aren't copies of the same file descriptor, the operating system doesn't guarantee anything about the order they'll be flushed in).

Comment: ...for example, if you run `exec > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)`, that'll create the conditions that allow this bug. Likewise, if the script this is in is run with its stdout and stderr being piped in different ways.

Comment: To be clear: The operations still _run_ in order; the problem the above creates one is the order in which output is written, which (when stdout and stderr aren't going to the same place) isn't guaranteed to be the same order things actually happened in.

Comment: Another way to cause a problem is to pipe standard output to `less`, in which case your script may be able to write its standard error before the standard output is read by, then written to the terminal, by `less`.

Comment: @chepner, ...though that would be reordering in the opposite direction; here, we have stdout showing up before stderr does.

Comment: Related: [redirect stdout and stderr to file and screen while preserving output ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282108/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-file-and-stderr-to-screen-while-preserving-output) -- it's basically certain your system is set up to do this in a way that _doesn't_ preserve ordering.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, right. But the race condition says that it could happen the other way, too :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I'm running the code in the Atom text editor. I looked into the script package for how it runs bash. I tried running directly using ./file.sh and the output is as behaved. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: @Diego, does Atom try to color stdout and stderr differently or otherwise distinguish between them? If so -- it can't do that without having them written to different FIFOs, but that means it doesn't have any way to be sure it's reading from those two FIFOs in the same order content was originally written. (If they're _not_ being handled differently, it's just sloppy to set it up this way, and Atom's authors can/should fix the bug).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My output isn't colored, though they might made it toggleable. I'm not really sure how it works...

Comment: BTW, a quick way to test this, if your OS is Linux: `ls -l /proc/self/fd`. If you run it in a terminal, it should look like `1 -> /dev/pts/2`, `2 -> /dev/pts/2` -- meaning both stdout and stderr are going to the same PTY. If you run it in your script from Atom, I'll bet they'll be going two different places. (The `2` in `/dev/pty/2` is an arbitrary number, it'll be different for each concurrently-running terminal).

Comment: ...in Atom, it'll probably look like `1 -> 'pipe:[123]'` and `2 -> 'pipe:[234]'` -- what's important is whether or not the `123` and `234` numbers are identical. If they're the same, the problem is not Atom's fault; if they're different, it totally is, and you should report the bug to Atom's authors instead of talking to us about it here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy using MacOS... seems that it doesn't use /proc folder. https://superuser.com/questions/631693/where-is-the-proc-folder-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Correct, that's why I said you could test that way "if your OS is Linux". I don't know, and don't care to know, if Apple has any equivalent.

Comment: That said, as a workaround... put `exec >&2` at the top of your script (just under the shebang) to make _everything_ be on stderr, or `exec 2>&1` at the top to make everything be on stdout. When content is all on the same stream, problems with the output from the streams being read out-of-order can't happen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that worked for me! I'm sure you diagnosed the source of my error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233905/discussion-between-diego-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the source code to [the Atom `script` plugin](https://github.com/atom-community/atom-script/blob/master/lib/runner.js), the problem becomes clear:

It creates a `BufferedProcess` *with separate stdout and stderr callbacks* (using them, among other things, to determine whether *any* output has been written to each of these streams).

Implementing this requires stdout and stderr to be directed to different FIFOs. This means that, unlike a typical terminal where there's an absolute ordering of which content was written to the single FIFO shared by both stdout and stderr at the same time, there's no strict guarantee that content will be processed through those functions in the same order it was written.

---

As a workaround, you can `exec 2>&1` into your script to put all content on stdout, or `exec >&2` to put all content on stderr. Ideally, if the `script` plugin doesn't need to track the two streams separately, it would do this itself, and put a callback only on the single stream to which all content has been redirected.